# decimal rounding to 2 precision such that X is converted to X.00 C#

Tags: c#, .net

First of all this is not a duplicate question my need is to have 2 precision decimal always

e.g. 
2 should be converted as 2.00 
0 should be converted as 0.00 
0.5 should be converted as 0.50

output number has to be decimal

Things i had tried

```
decimal val = 0.5000M
decimal d = Math.Round(val, 2);//gives 0.5 i need 0.50
```

**NOTE:** I am not looking to convert decimal to string as i need to send it as a soap request which accepts decimal value only, so i dont have flexibility to convert it to string.

**Update**
 below code as answered by Jakub Lortz works fine though it may look complex

## solution 1 by Jakub Lortz

`decimal twoPoint00 = new Decimal(200, 0, 0, false, 2);
decimal twoPoint0 = new Decimal(20, 0, 0, false, 1);
Console.WriteLine(twoPoint00) // prints 2.00
Console.WriteLine(twoPoint0)  // prints 2.0`

## solution 2 by Bogdan

he had given very simple solution which will also work

`decimal val = 0.5000M;

string result = string.Format("{0:f2}", val);
decimal d;
Decimal.TryParse(result, out d);`

Comment: Do you want as numeric value or as string?

Comment: Your issue seems more about how/where the value is displayed, rather than the actual precision itself. Where are you using the output?

Comment: actually i wanted to send it as a part of soap request where field is specified as decimal , so i want value as numeric to be precise decimal

Comment: Its not duplicate as above link deal with representing it in string, and i want it to be shown in decimal itself.

Comment: When it's decimal, `0.5` and `0.50` are exactly the same. When displaying somewhere (that is a `string`), there is a difference.

Comment: @AnshulNigam I don't think you ever display decimals... It's always converted to a string upon being displayed. And if you are not displaying it, wherever you are sending it too needs to deal with trailing 0s.

Comment: guys, please try to understand requirement, i can't convert it to string as i need to send it as soap request , also as it involves money calculations it is hard requirement to have to 2 decimal place.

Comment: @AnshulNigam That doesn't make sense. `0.5` and `0.50` are exactly the same number. The only difference is how they're displayed, which is absolutely a property of a string.

Comment: can you explain why returning the decimal `0.5` is incorrect when it is the same as `0.50`? TBH I think you are trying to deal with this in the wrong place - you need to deal with this on the presentation level.

Comment: @AnshulNigam Your requirement does not make sense. The service should recognize `0.5` and `0.50` as the *exact same number*. If it doesn't, then the service is ***fundamentally*** broken and your *only* option is to send it a string representing the number. The only other thing you could do is rounding (to fix cases such as `0.501`), which you have already sorted out yourself

Comment: I can't see where your soap request would recognize any difference between a `decimal` of value 2.5 and a _different_ (???) `decimal` of value 2.50

Comment: I agree with @RenéVogt and AnshulNigam.  The system should understand that 2.5 and 2.50 is the same number

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that you need to send this as part of a SOAP request. What technology are you using to communicate with the server? It seems your need pertains more to controlling how that SOAP request is created, rather than the details of the .NET decimal datatype. Although, it seems rather silly if a web service can't accept "2.5".

Comment: A down vote ? can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 5):

There is a [constructor of `Decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x.aspx) that allows you to specify the scale:

```
public Decimal(
    int lo,
    int mid,
    int hi,
    bool isNegative,
    byte scale
)
```

For example:

```
decimal twoPoint00 = new Decimal(200, 0, 0, false, 2);
decimal twoPoint0 = new Decimal(20, 0, 0, false, 1);
Console.WriteLine(twoPoint00) // prints 2.00
Console.WriteLine(twoPoint0)  // prints 2.0
```

This constructor is used by the C# compiler to create decimals from literals, so you can easily check it in the compiled IL.

**Edit**

To convert a decimal value to a representation with a set precision, you would first have to use [`Decimal.GetBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get its internal representation. Then modify the values (maybe using `BigInteger` to work with the whole 96-bits value as a whole?) and create a new decimal.

Seems like a lot of job, with a lot of possible bugs. I'd start by checking the solution proposed in [Bogdan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34228611/4588915) - `ToString()` + `Parse()`. It seems to work correctly and is very simple.

Comment: this sounds interesting and worth trying

Comment: This is really interesting, but I still wonder what strange soap request cares about that.

Comment: is there is some way to extract lo,mid,hi from a decimal variable?

Comment: @AnshulNigam There is. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @JakubLortz: This works like charm and i agree code will not be readable, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to convert the `decimal` into a string. Try it like that:

```
string result = d.ToString("#.00");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal val = 0.5000M;   
string result = string.Format("{0:f2}", val);
decimal d;
Decimal.TryParse(result, out d);
```

**@Jakub Lortz - Thank you for the suggestions:**

```
decimal val = 0.5000M;   
string formattedVal = val.ToString("F2"); 
decimal result = Decimal.Parse(formattedVal);
```

Comment: parsing a decimal to a string to a decimal is ridiculous

Comment: Do you think it works?

Comment: Thanks bogdan it worked.

Comment: @AnshulNigam in this code, what (which variable) holds your desired result?

Comment: Nice and simple. I'd suggest some small changes though. We don't need `string.Format`, `ToString()` is enough. And since we create the string, we don't need to worry about `Decimal.Parse` throwing an exception. So `string formattedVal = val.ToString("F2"); decimal result = Decimal.Parse(formattedVal);` is enough.

Comment: "@Arghya C @AnshulNigam in this code, what (which variable) holds your desired result?" - If you need the result as a STRING you have to use 'result', if you need a DECIMAL type you need to use 'd'.